# Confused about the use of def() in Python

Tags: python

So, a while ago I started a project for educational and entertainment purposes on creating a Python based interaction story.
I wrote the code snippet below but I'm confused about something. (Bear in mind I'm new to Python so if it's something simple don't be rude please) In the snippet below I can call the function before I write it. For example, the first one I call upon is "path_1_1()" which then prints the path_1_1() function below. I'm confused as to why I can't do this in other Python programs and scripts? Because it gives me a NameError and says the variable is not defined.

```
def meadow():
    print("You are in a tall grassy meadow\n\
there is lots of grass all around you\n\
however there are 2 paths\n\
the Train Rail Path\n\
or the Forest Path..")
    meadow_choice = input("Which path will you choose? : ")
    if meadow_choice =="Train Rail" or meadow_choice == "Train Rail Path" or meadow_choice == "train rail" or meadow_choice == "train rail path":
        print("You've chosen the Train Rail Path")
        path_1_1()
    elif meadow_choice =="Forest Path" or meadow_choice == "forest path" or meadow_choice == "Forest" or meadow_choice == "forest":
        print("You've chosen the Forest Path")
        path_1_2()
    else:
        print("Woops, that's not a choice, try again.")
        meadow()

# Train Rail Path 1.1  
def path_1_1():
    print("You walk up the train rail, cautious of\n\
oncoming trains. As you look around you spot a\n\
Small Note, and a Large hole..")
    path_1_1_choices =input("Which would you like to investigate, the Small Note, or the Large Hole? : ")
    if path_1_1_choices == "Small Note" or path_1_1_choices == "small note":
        print("You've chosen to investigate the Small Note")
        path_2_2_1()
    elif path_1_1_choices == "Large Hole" or path_1_1_choices == "large hole":
        print("You've chosen to investigate the Large Hole")
        path_2_1_1()
    else:
        print("Woops, that's not a choice, try again.")
        path_1_1()
```

Comment: You **can't** call a function before you declare it. Try to call `meadow` before you declare `path_1_1` and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, when you just define a function, you can call another function that comes later in the code.
However, when you call and execute the function, the called function should be pre defined.

```
def function_a():
    function_b()
    return 0

def function_b():
    pass
```

This is valid.

```
function_a()

def function_a():
    pass
```

This raises NameError, since function_a() was called before it was defined.

Comment: "when you just define a function, you can call another function" - No, you can't. The other function never gets called when the one using it gets defined.

Comment: @jeff pentagon so are you saying this only works because I have called a function within another function?

Comment: @luka essentially yes. it is therefore not a good practice to mix function definitions and execution blocks in 1 file. try to separate those in 2 different files. 1 file for function definitions, 1 file for execution. (of course you need to import called functions). In some cases like algorithm practicing platforms(leetcode, etc) you can't separate files. if that's the case, then always put the execution block at the bottom of your code after all the functions have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Python reads line one by one so when you call a fonction before writing it raises a `NameError`. However defining a fonction using `def` don't run any code, it only indicates to Python that the function exists and can be call further. So you can define all your functions first and, after that, call them without worrying about the order in which they are called.

Comment: " it only indicates to Python that the function exists " - it doesn't. It is only when trying to call it that the interpreter will complain if nothing executable with this name exists.

Comment: @Valentin Goldité but I don't understand why that script works then? Because I did not define the functions before calling them, I defined them after / EDIT: So I realised that I put "meadow()" around the parts of the script, which is what prevents NameError. Thanks for the help all